# Listview button is partially visible on UI even with HasUnevenRows

Tags: maui

I am facing a weird issue with `listview`. I have a button in my `listview` and it is not completely visible on UI like below screenshot:

[image]

**My code:**

**MainPage.xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ListviewDemo.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <ListView  
            Margin="5"
            SeparatorColor="#cecece"
            x:Name="datalistview"
            HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout 
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                            Orientation="Vertical" 
                            Padding="5" 
                            Margin="5">

                            <Label 
                                Text="{Binding title}"
                                Style="{StaticResource RequestListviewStyle}"/>

                            <Label 
                                Margin="0,5,0,0"
                                Text="{Binding description}"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                                <Label.FontSize>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                        <OnIdiom.Phone>15</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>23</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>15</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                    </OnIdiom>
                                </Label.FontSize>
                            </Label>

                            <StackLayout
                                Margin="0,5,0,0"
                                Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <Label 
                                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                    Text="{Binding time}">
                                    <Label.FontSize>
                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                            <OnIdiom.Phone>12</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>18</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>12</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                        </OnIdiom>
                                    </Label.FontSize>
                                </Label>

                                <Button 
                                    Text="New"
                                    TextColor="White"
                                    BackgroundColor="#81c124"
                                    HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                    Style="{StaticResource MyRequesterButtonStyle}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.Footer>
                <Label/>
            </ListView.Footer>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security.AccessControl;

namespace ListviewDemo
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Data> dataCollection;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataCollection = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
            SetData();
        }
        
        private void SetData()
        {
            dataCollection.Clear();
            dataCollection.Add(new Data() { title = "data 1", description = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.", time = "01-01-2023" });
            dataCollection.Add(new Data() { title = "data 1", description = "It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.", time = "01-01-2023" });
            dataCollection.Add(new Data() { title = "data 1", description = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.", time = "01-01-2023" });
            dataCollection.Add(new Data() { title = "data 1", description = "It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.", time = "01-01-2023" });
            datalistview.ItemsSource = dataCollection;
        }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string time { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Styles:**

```
<Style x:Key="RequestListviewStyle" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize">
        <OnIdiom
        x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
        Phone="17"
        Tablet="26"
        Desktop="17"/>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="MyRequesterButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Start"/>
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{OnIdiom Phone=20, Tablet=40}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize">
        <OnIdiom
            x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
            Phone="12"
            Tablet="21"
            Desktop="14"/>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="HeightRequest">
        <OnIdiom
            x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
            Phone="35"
            Tablet="60"
            Desktop="40"/>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="WidthRequest">
        <OnIdiom
            x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
            Phone="120"
            Tablet="225"
            Desktop="150"/>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Listview has `HasUnevenRows="True"` property. I tried a lot to find out the reason behind this, but no luck.

I have created a demo project and uploaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1at_Z5f-8oC3DZssiLDRAejbKbAEa--GZ/view?usp=sharing) for easy reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I can reproduce. It only happens on Android. Work well on iOS.

Here are workarounds.

1.Use Grid instead of StackLayout

```
<Grid
   Margin="0,5,0,0"
   >

   <Label 
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
       HorizontalOptions="Start"
       HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
       Text="{Binding time}">
       ...
   </Label>

   <Button 
       Text="New"
       TextColor="White"
       .../>
</Grid>
```

2.Add the below margin for android

```
<StackLayout
     Margin="0,5,0,20"
     Orientation="Horizontal">
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17683

Answer (score 1):

Instead of nested StackLayout, you could use Grid to easily manage content-disposition:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
        <Grid RowDefinitions="auto,auto,auto"
              ColumnDefinitions="*,auto"
              Margin="10">
            <Label Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                   Text="{Binding title}"
                   Style="{StaticResource RequestListviewStyle}"/>

            <Label Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                   Margin="0,5,0,0"
                   Text="{Binding description}"
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                <Label.FontSize>
                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                        <OnIdiom.Phone>15</OnIdiom.Phone>
                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>23</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>15</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                    </OnIdiom>
                </Label.FontSize>
            </Label>

            <Label Grid.Row="2"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                   Text="{Binding time}">
                <Label.FontSize>
                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                        <OnIdiom.Phone>12</OnIdiom.Phone>
                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>18</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>12</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                    </OnIdiom>
                </Label.FontSize>
            </Label>

            <Button Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Text="New"
                    TextColor="White"
                    BackgroundColor="#81c124"
                    HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                    Style="{StaticResource MyRequesterButtonStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

That approach could solve your issue.
I would suggest also not using ViewCell if it's not strictly needed.